# What is causing DataDog widgets to display http status code as N/A

Tags: spring-boot, datadog

My organization is setting up dashboards for our backend services and after performance testing that we ran, we have noticed that some API calls report http status `N\A`.

[image]

[image]

It is not very helpful, anyone seen something like that? 
Is that a configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like some of your `http.server.requests.count` metric values do not have any `status` tag, so when you group by the `status` tag, those are being aggregaed with a value of `n/a`.

If it is intentional/expected that this metric would have values without the `status` tag and you just want to ignored those metric values, then you can use the `exclude_null()` function to remove that tag grouping from your graph (docs [here](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/functions/beta/#exclude-null)).

If it is not intentional/expected that this metric would have values without the `status` tag, then you probably want to reach out to support@datadoghq.com to get that looked into.

Comment: it is not intentional, I would expect every HTTP server request to have a status code.